# Output from child to parent component doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to pass data from child to parent component but it doesn't work in a proper way: function isn't invoked.

```
    <router-outlet (activeElement)='getActive($event)'></router-outlet>
    <div class="myDIV"> 
    <button *ngFor="let i of numberOfButtons" (click)="navigate(i)"  [ngClass]="(i === active) ? 'btn active': 'btn'">{{i}}</button>
    </div>
```

child component ts.file

```
@Output() activeElement = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,private getPlanets:GetPlanetsService,private router: Router, private renderer:Renderer2,private elRef: ElementRef) { 
    activatedRoute.params.subscribe(value=>{
      this.fivePlanetIndex=value.id;
      this.activeElement.emit(value.id);
    });
  }
```

parent component .ts file

```
  getActive(i){
    console.log(i); //it is not invoked
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Output` will work by using component selector, not with `router-outlet`.
Because `router-outlet` used to render multiple components and it doesn't make sense to set all `Input`s and `Output`s on there.

If you wanna use `router-outlet` and catch events from children components, you can use `Observable`s; where child component send result and parent component subscribe to it.

**sample.service.ts**

```
// you will use subject to emit event from child
subject = new Subject<any>();
// you will use observable to listen to events from parent
observable = this.subject.asObservable();
```

**child.component.ts**

```
constructor(service: SampleService) {}

// instead of emit function
this.service.subject.next();
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
constructor(service: SampleService) {}

// instead of event listener 
this.service.observable.subscribe();
```

Comment: I have issue with part "instead of event listener". Regards

Comment: Nothing special my friend, you use (activeElement)='getActive($event)' in HTML and i called it event listener, that's it.

Comment: what should be named activeElement

Comment: It will be separated into 2 variables, one to send from child, which represents subject variable, and one to watch events which represent observable

Comment: I did:

 constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,private activeService:ActiveService,private getPlanets:GetPlanetsService,private router: Router, private renderer:Renderer2,private elRef: ElementRef) { 
    activatedRoute.params.subscribe(value=>{
      this.fivePlanetIndex=value.id;
      this.activeService.subject.next(value.id)
    });
  }


But i have issue with receiving data in parent because i need to be possible changing active element by URL for ex. /1 or /2

Comment: Okay, about parent component?
you should put:
constructor(private activeService:ActiveService) {}
this.activeService.observable.subscribe(id => { // here you will get events })